# Delete route and point from map

Tags: openlayers, openstreetmap, openlayers-6

I need to delete the route and all the point present in the map by click on a button or firing an event.
This is the code I use to write the route on the map.

https://pastebin.com/qnBce4y3

I tryed this way to delete the layers but I'm not able to choose the correct layer,the result is that the route remain on the map but the map layer is deleted.

```
  this.map.getLayers().getArray().map(layer => {
    layer.setVisible(false);
    return true;enter code here
});
```

How can I do?
Thanks
Andrea

Answer (score 0):

If you keep a reference to the layer when you create it

```
 this.vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    features: [routeFeature, geoMarker, startMarker, endMarker],
  }),
  style: function (feature) {
    // hide geoMarker if animation is active
    if (animating && feature.get('type') === 'geoMarker') {
      return null;
    }
    return styles[feature.get('type')];
  },
});
this.map.addLayer(this.vectorLayer);
```

It is easy to remove the correct layer

```
this.map.removeLayer(this.vectorLayer);
```

Comment: I tried it but is not work, nothing change in my map if I use your code...